# Spark Structured Streaming Writestream to Hive ORC Partioned External Table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-structured-streaming, orc, hive-partitions

I am trying to use Spark Structured Streaming - `writeStream` API to write to an External Partitioned Hive table.

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `XX`(
`a` string,
`b` string,
`b` string,
`happened` timestamp,
`processed` timestamp,
`d` string,
`e` string,
`f` string )
 PARTITIONED BY (
`year` int, `month` int, `day` int)      
 CLUSTERED BY (d)
INTO 6 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC 
TBLPROPERTIES (
'orc.compress'='ZLIB',
'orc.compression.strategy'='SPEED',
'orc.create.index'='true',
'orc.encoding.strategy'='SPEED');
```

and in Spark code,

```scala
val hiveOrcWriter:   DataStreamWriter[Row] = event_stream
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("orc")
  .partitionBy("year","month","day")
  //.option("compression", "zlib")
  .option("path", _table_loc)
  .option("checkpointLocation", _table_checkpoint)
```

I see that on a non partition table, records are inserted into Hive. However, on using partitioned table, the spark job does not fail or raise exceptions but records are not inserted to Hive table.

Appreciate comments from anyone who has dealt with similar problems.

**Edit**:

Just discovered that the .orc files are indeed written to the HDFS, withe correct partition directory structure: eg. `/_table_loc/_table_name/year/month/day/part-0000-0123123.c000.snappy.orc`

However

```sql
select * from 'XX' limit 1; (or where year=2018)
```

returns no rows.

The `InputFormat` and `OutputFormat` for the Table 'XX' are `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat` and 
`org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat` respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature isn't provided out of the box in structured streaming. In normal processing, you would use `dataset.write.saveAsTable(table_name)` , and that method isn't available.

After processing and saving the data in HDFS, you can manually update the partitions (or using a script that does this on a schedule):

If you use Hive

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name
```

If you use Impala

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RECOVER PARTITIONS
```